# While loop causing error R6010 Visual C++ Express 2013

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program to find the primes within a certain interval and then store them in a vector.

It compiles but when it reaches the loop and I get error R6010 (" -abort has been called" i.e.). I am using Visual C++ Express 2013. std_lib_facilities.h is from Stroustrups PPP.

```
 /* User picks a max and min number. A loop tests each value
    within the interval as x modulus --x where x decrements per loop*/

 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "std_lib_facilities.h"

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    vector<int>prime;

    cout << "Input max number: ";
    cin >> x; 
    z = x;
    cout << "Inupt min number: ";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "You have entered the interval " << x << " to " << y << ".\n";
    //Loop for calculating primes
    while (x>=y) {
        while (x > 0) {
            //find primes for z
            if (z%x != 0) {
                prime.push_back(x);
                cout << prime[x] << "\n";
                x--;
            } else {
                x--; //try a new value
            }
        }
        z--;
        x=z; //find out if z decremented is a prime
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
cout << prime[x] << "\n";
```

You are using the prime number `x` as an index into the vector of primes, which is almost certain to go past the end of the vector.

You should simply print `x`, because it is the prime you just pushed, not its location in the vector of primes:

```
cout << x << "\n";
```